# Reading Metadata added using AddMetaData method in MEF 2.0

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to use RegistrationBuilder from MEF 2.0 in my application. I have modified my classes to not use the Export/Import attributes.
Also I am adding MetaData to the exported parts using the following statement (based on the code sample from the "Configuring the export" section of [MEF’s Convention model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/archive/2011/03/17/10138440.aspx?Redirected=true)):

```
var registration= new RegistrationBuilder();
// Export of the Interface which the classes implement
//registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ITransactionInterface>().Export<ITransactionInterface>();

//export of the types derived from ITransactionInterface            
registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ITransactionInterface>()
            .Export(configData=>configData.AddMetadata("Name",t=>t.Name))
            .Export<ITransactionInterface>();
```

I am doing the imports of the exported parts (using Lazy Imports) using the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Lazy<ItransactionInterface>> txnObjects= container.GetExports<ITransactionInterface>();
```

Now how do i **access the Metadata** of the exported class parts?

Any help is much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to access the metadata is by adding a metadata interface like:

```
public interface ITransactionMetadata
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

And then use the [CompositionContainer.GetExports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833495%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload with the metadata view parameter:

```
IEnumerable<Lazy<ITransactionInterface, ITransactionMetadata>> txnObjects = container.GetExports<ITransactionInterface, ITransactionMetadata>();
```

Then you can easily access the metadata:

```
foreach (var export in txnObjects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t Name = {0}", export.Metadata.Name);
}
```

Finally note that you need to export the exact type that you want to import. In your case you import `ITransactionInterface` but you export the type implementing the interface. You need to change the registration to:

```
registration.ForTypesDerivedFrom<ITransactionInterface>()
            .Export<ITransactionInterface>(configData => configData.AddMetadata("Name", t => t.Name));
```